# C# how to find a value in a List collection

Tags: c#

I have a list this list contains a collection of the following class

```
public class MyFile
{
    public string FileName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Position
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

So ofc the list definition will look like this:

```
private List<MyFile> MyFiles = new List<MyFile>();
```

I can also search the collection using:

```
MyFile tmpFile = MyFiles.Find(delegate(MyFile item) 
   { return item.FileName == fileName; });
```

So far looking good, except what I would like to do is return the MyFile that not only matches the file name but that also has the highest value in field pos.

So if the following items exist in the list:

```
myDocument.doc|1
myDocument.doc|2
myDocument.doc|3
myPDF.pdf|1
myPDF.pdf|2
myPDF.pdf|3
```

and the value of fileName = "myDocument.doc" in my find method, then I am still missing logic to return myDocument.doc|3 this item, because this has the highest value of pos.

In SQL my query would be

```
select top 1 * from MyFiles 
where fileName = 'myDocument.doc' 
order by position desc;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5, or some earlier version?

Comment: using 3.5 so no problems there.

Answer (score 11):

Can you use Linq?  If so, a simple query like this should do:

```
MyFile file = MyFiles.Where(f => f.FileName == fileName).OrderByDescending(f => f.Position).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Just a couple minutes late.  (c:

Comment: You'll want to use FirstOrDefault in case the Where returns an empty set.  Doesn't that throw an Exception?

Comment: True it throws an exception, testing now with first or default.

Comment: indeed, `FirstOrDefault` would do better

Answer (score 3):

This is easy using LINQ or extension methods if you're using above .Net 2.0:

```
MyFile tmpFile = MyFiles.Where(file => file.FileName == "myDocument.doc").OrderByDescending(file => file.Position).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class MyFileList: List<MyFile> 
{
    public MyFile this[string filName]
    {
       get 
       {
          int maxPos = int.MinValue;
          MyFile retFile = null;
          foreach(MyFile fil in this)
             if (fil.FileName == filName && 
                 fil.Position > maxPos)
             {
                 maxPos = fil.Position;
                 retFile= fil;
             }
          return retFile;
       }
    }
}
```